# MySQL most price change over time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, window-functions

```sql
price | date       | product_id
100   | 2020-09-21 | 1
400   | 2020-09-20 | 2
300   | 2020-09-20 | 3
200   | 2020-09-19 | 1
400   | 2020-09-18 | 2
```

I add an entry into this table every day with a product's price that day.

Now I want to get most price drops for the last week (all dates up to 2020-09-14), in this example it would only return the `product_id = 1`, because that's the only thing that changed.

I think I have to join the table to itself, but I'm not getting it to work.

Here's something that I wanted to return the most price changes over the last day, however it's not working.

```sql
select pt.price, pt.date, pt.product_id, (pt.price - py.price) as change
from prices as pt
inner join (
    select *
    from prices
    where date > '2020-09-20 19:33:43'
) as py
on pt.product_id = py.product_id
where pt.price - py.price > 0
order by change
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to count how many times the price of each product changed over the last 7 days.

A naive approach would use aggregation and `count(distinct price)` - but it fails when a product's price changes back and forth.

A safer approach is window functions: you can use `lag()` to retrieve the previous price, and compare it against the current price; it is then easy to aggregate and count the price changes:

```
select product_id, sum(price <> lag_price) cnt_price_changes
from (
    select t.*, lag(price) over(partition by product_id order by date) lag_price
    from mytable t
    where date >= current_date - interval 7 day
) t
group by product_id
order by price_changes desc
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. Wondering though, can I order  by `price_diff` instead of `price_changes`? What I mean is this orders by number of price changes, would be nice if the biggest price difference came first and then descended (percentage difference or just `price - lag_price` maybe). Could be a different problem altogether..

Comment: @himmip: the query aggregates all price changes per product. Say you want to order by the biggest price change per product: `order by max(abs(price - lag_price)) desc`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MAX()` and `MIN()` instead....

```
select MAX(pt.price), MIN(pt.price), MAX(pt.price) - MIN(pt.price) as change
from prices as pt
inner join (
    select *
    from prices
    where date > '2020-09-20 19:33:43'
) as py
on pt.product_id = py.product_id
order by change
```

Instead of subtracting every row by every other row to get the result, you can find the max and min's easily by means of [**`MAX()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_min) and [**`MIN()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_min), and, ultimately, `**MAX() - MIN()**`.  Relevant lines from the linked MySQL documentation...

> `MAX()`: Returns the maximum value of expr.
>
> `MIN()`: Returns the minimum value of expr.

You won't be able to pull the other fields (id's, dates) since this is a `GROUP BY()` implied by the `MAX()` and `MIN()`, but you should then be able to get that info by query `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE price = MAX_VALUE_JUST_ACQUIRED`.

Answer (score 0):

This examples will get you results per `WeekOfYear` and `WeekOfMonth` regarding the lowering of the price per product.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(m1.product_id) as total,
m1.product_id,
WEEK(m1.ddate) AS weekofyear 
FROM mytest m1
WHERE m1.price < (SELECT m2.price FROM mytest m2 WHERE m2.ddate<m1.ddate AND m1.product_id=m2.product_id LIMIT 0,1)
GROUP BY weekofyear,m1.product_id 
ORDER BY weekofyear;

SELECT 
COUNT(m1.product_id) as total,
m1.product_id,
FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(ddate) - 1) / 7) + 1 AS weekofmonth
FROM mytest m1
WHERE m1.price < (SELECT m2.price FROM mytest m2 WHERE m2.ddate<m1.ddate AND m1.product_id=m2.product_id LIMIT 0,1)
GROUP BY weekofmonth,m1.product_id 
ORDER BY weekofmonth;
```

Try this out in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/084ec2/10).